# how to apply wysiwyg editor to textarea tag

Tags: php, html

Does anyone of you knows what script or how can I add html editor to my textarea tag?

For ex i have the following
`<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">Initial value</textarea>`

what should I do next in order to add those editor tools.

btw, i have seen ckeditor but i cdnt manage to work it :S.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor

Answer (score 2):

I would recommand you first actually search for this.
Example tutorial / instructions: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SU6YWME914A
And most importantly http://docs.cksource.com/

Should contain every instruction you need.

Good luck.

Comment: in my case i need it to integrate in php,

is CKEditor right one for php, or i have to look for another one?? i cant see from official site saying for php anything.

btw thanks it looks a nice tutorial, i will watch at it.

Comment: Wether you need to integrate it in HTML, PHP or anything. ckeditor consits of javascript. You will need to include the correct javascript code in the header of your website. Alternatively ckeditor gives the possibillity to include it directly in PHP as well. I highly recommand you check the "examples" folder of ckeditor, it contains all examples you need and should give much clarification :-)

Comment: I have this, and still not working:

 <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">Initial value<textarea>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
   </script>

Comment: Again, ckeditor consits of javascript. You will need to include the correct javascript code in the header of your website. I am quite sure you didn't do this. Check the examples and you will see for yourself what you're missing.

Comment: i have included inside header this

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

Comment: I fix it out, thank you very much , you know what was the problem, u not gonna believe it :P. 

I just removed the first slash from here src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script> to src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>